# How many elements of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^n$ are scalar multiples of a fixed non-zero $n$-tuple $x$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Imagine that you have a fixed, non-zero $n$-tuple $x$, such that values in $x$ belong to $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^n$, where $p$ is prime. In other words, if, for example, our prime $p$ was $7$ and the value of $n$ was $3$, a possible value of $x$ could be
$$
(1, 5, 3).
$$

The actual question is the following:
How many elements on the aforementioned set $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^n$ are scalar multiples of $x$?

This is not one of my homework problems, although I am currently getting into Abstract Algebra through one of my courses. I would appreciate any and all help, since I have been trying to figure out a nice way to approach this for quite some time now.

Comment: Those scalar multiples form a 1-dimensional vector space. What does a 1-dimensional vector space look like ?

Comment: Hint: to get a feel for this problem, try computing out specific examples. For example we can take $x = (1,5,3)$ when $p = 7$. What are $2x, 3x, 4x, $ and so on? Do you notice any patterns?

Comment: The answer is $p$

Comment: it says in the title that the vector is non-zero @aras

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Ah, OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is $p$ because if $av = bv$ we have $(a-b)v=0$. If you look at one of the coordinates where $a$ is not $0$ you will see that $a-b$ must be $0$ and so we are done.

Comment: Although I don't quite follow your reasoning here, the answer is correct and I appreciate it!

Comment: No problem bro, all is well that ends well. Edit: I found the problem and fixed it.